# DNS Leak OpenVPN dnsmasq

Tags: dns, vpn, dnsmasq

I have configured Ubuntu 16.04 with OpenVPN and when connected to the tunnel Ubuntu is using DNS servers from my VPN (which is what I want) but it is also using one DNS server from network/interfaces which is causing a DNS leak.

I removed dnsmasq and checked `resolv.conf` and I can see 3 DNS in the list, the first two from my VPN and third from network/interfaces.

How do I configure the system to only use DNS provided by my VPN provider?

Comment: DNS leaks are not intended behavior. If the behavior can be replicated in the current pre-release version of Ubuntu (18.04), then please use the `ubuntu-bug` application to report the bug. If the behavior cannot be replicated in a recent release, then the bug has already been fixed. Not all bugfixes are backported to older releases.

Comment: Ok i will update to 18.04 and check

Comment: When is 18.04 released cannot find it on site

Comment: No, don't *upgrade* to a pre-release version of Ubuntu. Download the iso, boot from a USB, and *test* only.

Comment: Have seen that before - i am not using network manager and my system is leaving the dns from network/interfaces instead of using only the VPN dns